# Getting a part from the date with tmap

Tags: talend

I have a date value '311211' having format 'ddmmyy'.

How can i get the part of the day ,the part of the month and the part of the year by using a function with tmap component in talend open studio.

Comment: do u want day, month and year individually??

Answer (score 4):

No need to use functions....:),

You can get the required result by setting **tMap** settings as follows..

please have a look at highlighted part in the following image

[image]

the output will be like..,

[image]

Comment: Absolutely the best way since many people don't seem to understand the different concepts of the date field and date formatting.

Comment: @tobi6 probably because the pattern is use to parse AND format depending it is for an input or output. Especially in that case where you use the same Date instance but with distinct pattern for the `String` formatting.

Answer (score 1):

String year = TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy", TalendDate.parseDate("ddMMyy", "311211"));

String month = TalendDate.formatDate("MM", TalendDate.parseDate("ddMMyy", "311211"));

String day = TalendDate.formatDate("dd", TalendDate.parseDate("ddMMyy", "311211"));

hope this helps...

Comment: Since you are in a tMap, you could create a variable Date to only parse it once ;) and reuse it. This is less verbose like this.